# Notified when lateinit var has been initialised (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

This is a straight forward question but I cannot find an answer. Is there a way to be notified when a `lateinit var` has been initialised in Kotlin?

I know I can check if it has been initialised with `this::coolvar.isInitialized` but this is not the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lateinit var` works well only in the simplest cases when uninitialized value doesn't make sense in the context of the app, such as dependency injection or late initialization in `onCreate()`.

What you need is a property delegate with a particular behavior. Take a look at [`Delegates.observable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html) :

```
var coolvar by Delegates.observable("initial value") { _, old, new ->
    println("coolvar has been updated")
}
```

Comment: This cannot be used in an inherited class I assume?

Comment: There are no restrictions. Use it the same way as a property with custom get/set, e.i. all goes except overriding the getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin coroutines you can handle it with delay() function.
for complex scenarios. not like a direct one if the value changes call this function.

Example:

```
private var lateinit extractFilesThread: Deferred<Unit>

private fun init() {
  GlobalScope.async {loadData()}
  GlobalScope.async {doSomeWork()}
}

private suspend fun loadData() {
  extractFilesThread = GlobalScope.async { 
    initialFilesManager.extractDataIfNeeded() 
  }
}

private suspend fun doSomeWork() {
  GlobalScope.async {
    waitExtractFilesThread()
    startThisWork()
  }
}


private suspend fun waitExtractFilesThread() {
  while (!::extractFilesThread.isInitialized) {
    delay(HALF_SECOND_IN_MILI)
  }
  extractFilesThread.await()
}
```

so here you want to call startThisWork() after extractFilesThread Finished
and you can't use await() only if it's already initialized, so we use delay() function, It's a suspend function so it won't block other function executions.